# How to refresh a grid in silverlight, when a launched window closes?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, telerik-grid, silverlight-5.0

I am launching a window using `HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(Uri, "_blank");` from a Grid row using a context menu for some custom editing specific to a page referred by the row. I am using telerik-grid in silver-light. I want to refresh the grid when user closes that window. How can i do this?

Please share some idea on, Is this possible? or where to look for start to tackle this?

**UPDATE**: I am using Silver-light **MVVM** model. The child window I am opening from silver-light is the the web browser, I would actually need a technique where I can have the grid in the silver light application to get refreshed when I close the web browser. Additionally i am using **RIA service** to expose the methods for the web browser.

Comment: This does not seem possible to me at first...have you considered maybe using the Telerik HTML Placeholder Control (http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#HtmlPlaceholder/FirstLook)?

Comment: @Misha Thanks, but i don't want to open inside silver light.

Answer (score 2):

Expose a method in your Silverlight app that is accessible from Javascript.

```
namespace SilverlightApplication
{
    public partial class Page : UserControl
    {
        public Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("Page", this);            
        }

        [ScriptableMember]
        public void UpdateDataGrid()
        {
            myDataGridItemsReload(); // your routine
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the newly opened window, you can execute a method on the Silverlight instance

```
<script>
    window.onunload = refreshParentGrid;
    function refreshParentGrid() {
        var hostDiv = window.opener.document.getElementById("silverlightControlHost");
        var control = hostDiv.children[0];           
        control.Content.Page.UpdateDataGrid();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I am using Silver-light MVVM model so I am wondering how the above snippet is used in view modal. The child window I am opening from silver-light is the the web browser, I would actually need a technique where I can have the grid in the silver light application to get refreshed when I close the web browser.

Comment: You can actually register a viewmodel with RegisterScriptableObject. However, you need to call into HtmlPage. You'll need to modify your Mvvm Framework to keep your viewmodel pure.

Comment: I am getting `var control = window.opener.document.getElementById("silverlightShellHost");` but not getting control.Content.Page.UpdateDataGrid(); even control.Content what to do for getting this?

Comment: You've got the host, not the silverlight control. You need to do this: var slcontrol = control.children[0];